# Is there a way to set rotation on inset maps to match data driven maps

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have been playing with the new map book functionality in ArcGIS 10 to re-create maps I have made in the past. The new Data Driven maps with page queries is a pretty powerful tool.

Is there a way to match the rotation of inset map, secondary data frame, with the main layer being used for the data driven maps? I found it is possible to match the extent in the 'Data Frame' tab of the 'Data Frame Properties', is this also the place to find the rotation option?

If this is something that you need to code, is it possible to build it into the mxd and to have it launch on refresh?

Not sure I understand how Python is supposed to work within a mxd.

Comment: So is there a way to write a python script that can do this with the new arcpy.mapping??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2 Data frames to be rotated in sync can be done if you set a field with rotation value
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_a_field_to_define_the_rotation_angle/0103000000m2000000/

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Choosing_a_spatial_reference_based_on_a_field/01030000011s000000/

you can sync inset maps with arcmap bookmarks and the 'extent indicators'
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000005000000.htm

Note: Bookmarks are stored in .mxds however 'My Places' do not (separate file .dat)

Comment: I do not have access to the MPS tools that the help system link you created refer to. I am using the data driven pages tools recommended by ESRI in ArcGIS10.

Comment: You can do it in VBA http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000011p000000

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe I am missing something in your question. Do you want to automatically sync the inset and the map frame?

If not then when you turn on the data frame tools toolbar you will see a rotation pick. You would just set the inset active and rotate it the same as your main data frame.

Comment: I am working with the new datya driven pages, so each map is setup using the data driven pages information, and for the main layer the rotation is also set.

Comment: I see so many pages would be difficult to apply that to.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of Data Driven Pages seems to be streached by your request. This seems to go back to the simplicity of the environment. Data Driven Pages is a way of creating a simple Map Series in Core ArcGIS and is replacing the functionality of DS Mapbook which is an unsupport developer sample.

I am unsure if this is possible but I do know that it is possible in Production Mapping using the Data Frame Manager, and the Synchronization options held. Another software purchase may not be available to you but just letting you know the functionality exists

Have Fun,
CDB